# Issue with ionic cordova run android

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, ionic4, ionic-native

I try to run my ionic 4 project on android but the build fail.

39 actionable tasks: 10 executed, 29 up-to-date
/appionic4/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

/appionic4/platforms/android/app/src/main/java/plugin/google/maps/PluginMap.java:91: error: cannot find symbol
    GoogleMap.OnMyLocationClickListener, GoogleMap.OnPoiClickListener,
             ^
  symbol:   class OnMyLocationClickListener
  location: class GoogleMap

/appionic4/platforms/android/app/src/main/java/plugin/google/maps/PluginStreetViewPanorama.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.StreetViewSource;
                                        ^
  symbol:   class StreetViewSource
  location: package com.google.android.gms.maps.model

/appionic4/platforms/android/app/src/main/java/plugin/google/maps/PluginLocationService.java:461: error: cannot find symbol
      LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(cordova.getActivity())
                      ^
  symbol:   method getFusedLocationProviderClient(Activity)
  location: class LocationServices

/appionic4/platforms/android/app/src/main/java/plugin/google/maps/PluginLocationService.java:521: error: cannot find symbol
    LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(cordova.getActivity()).requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, new LocationCallback() {
                    ^
  symbol:   method getFusedLocationProviderClient(Activity)
  location: class LocationServices

/appionic4/platforms/android/app/src/main/java/plugin/google/maps/PluginMap.java:428: error: cannot find symbol
              map.setOnMyLocationClickListener(PluginMap.this);
                 ^
  symbol:   method setOnMyLocationClickListener(PluginMap)
  location: variable map of type GoogleMap

/appionic4/platforms/android/app/src/main/java/plugin/google/maps/PluginMap.java:846: error: cannot find symbol
                  map.setOnMyLocationClickListener(null);
                     ^
  symbol:   method setOnMyLocationClickListener()
  location: variable map of type GoogleMap

/appionic4/platforms/android/app/src/main/java/plugin/google/maps/PluginMap.java:2769: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
  @Override
  ^

/appionic4/platforms/android/app/src/main/java/plugin/google/maps/PluginStreetViewPanorama.java:87: error: cannot find symbol
          StreetViewSource source = "OUTDOOR".equals(cameraOpts.getString("source")) ?
          ^
  symbol:   class StreetViewSource
  location: class PluginStreetViewPanorama

/appionic4/platforms/android/app/src/main/java/plugin/google/maps/PluginStreetViewPanorama.java:88: error: cannot find symbol
              StreetViewSource.OUTDOOR : StreetViewSource.DEFAULT;
              ^
  symbol:   variable StreetViewSource
  location: class PluginStreetViewPanorama

/appionic4/platforms/android/app/src/main/java/plugin/google/maps/PluginStreetViewPanorama.java:88: error: cannot find symbol
              StreetViewSource.OUTDOOR : StreetViewSource.DEFAULT;
                                         ^
  symbol:   variable StreetViewSource
  location: class PluginStreetViewPanorama

/appionic4/platforms/android/app/src/main/java/plugin/google/maps/PluginStreetViewPanorama.java:280: error: cannot find symbol
              StreetViewSource source = "OUTDOOR".equals(cameraOpts.getString("source")) ?
              ^
  symbol: class StreetViewSource

/appionic4/platforms/android/app/src/main/java/plugin/google/maps/PluginStreetViewPanorama.java:281: error: cannot find symbol
                  StreetViewSource.OUTDOOR : StreetViewSource.DEFAULT;
                  ^
  symbol: variable StreetViewSource

/appionic4/platforms/android/app/src/main/java/plugin/google/maps/PluginStreetViewPanorama.java:281: error: cannot find symbol
                  StreetViewSource.OUTDOOR : StreetViewSource.DEFAULT;
                                             ^
  symbol: variable StreetViewSource

Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
13 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

  > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s

How can I fix this ? Thank you!

Comment: Uninstall and reinstall your google maps plugin. It looks like it wasn't installed correctly: `ionic cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-googlemaps` then `ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-googlemaps --variable API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID="..." --variable API_KEY_FOR_IOS="..."`

Comment: this problem also occurs with ionic 3, I think its a problem with the version of google maps.

Answer (score 0):

this problem also occurs with ionic 3, I think its a problem with the version of google maps. Check the version of the google maps to be used with ionic 4.